# Mysql very slow Join Performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm hoping someone can advise, but I'm experiencing very long processing times around the following join statement, and was hoping to get some suggestions on improving performance. Both tables have millions of records in each, and I have column indexes on, but it's still taking over 70 hours to run this join.

```
update <table x> a
left join <table y> b
on a.PARENT_ID=b.ID and a.LOAD_ID=b.LOADID                    
set a.DATETIME=str_to_date(b.`DateTime`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'), a.ROOM_ID=b.ConID, a.STATUS='Exited'
where a.PARENT_ID=b.ID and a.LOAD_ID=b.LOADID and a.PROCESSING_FLAG = 0 and b.PROCESSING_FLAG = 0
```

So table x has 66m records, and table y has 44m, but using the PROCESSING_FLAG it won't be joining all 66m records to 44m records, only a subset.  I have column indexes on a.Parent_Id, b.ID, a.Load_ID, b.LoadID, a.Room_ID, b.ConID, a.Processing_Flag, and b.Processing_Flag.  Both tables use MYISAM and I'm using MySQL 5.6.17.

Is there anyhting I can do to improve the performance of this statement?  I was thinking of increasing the key buffer perhaps to 6G as a first step.

Comment: Did you try running it through EXPLAIN to see if it is actually using the indexes you think it is?

Comment: PROCESSING_FLAG is apparently 0 or 1, therefore its cardinality is useless - whether you index that or not, MySQL will still go trough entire data set to determine certain records aren't needed. I don't see a single satisfactory criteria for efficient index use in that query. Next silly thing is that you're using MyISAM for some odd reason, so you're I/O bound since RAM is most likely not used to store hot copy of working data set. I doubt this can be optimized whatsoever without using a more advanced storage engine that can utilise RAM efficiently.

Comment: I haven't yet as the statement is still running, and there locked the tables.

Comment: Yes Processing flag is set as a bit so either 1 or 0.  The idea is that I get data in chucks, and each chuck gets processed.  So I wanted a way of only new data being processed and not the old stuff.

Comment: Using MYISAM because I read somewhere that it's faster.  I don't use Innodb because this is not an application so don't need primary and foreign keys and do need ACID compliance. I tend to get denormalised data.

Comment: Would it make a difference if the processing flag was either Y or N?

Comment: So what's the best way then to ensure MySQL optionally works through this dataset?

Comment: Question is, what are you trying to do? I get the part with 66m + 44m rows, but how are you using the info in those rows? Is this for some sort of task processing? MySQL isn't always the best choice for queue information and such. Personally, I'd convert this to InnoDB for start. Alternatively, at least an SSD would help there, if you don't want to switch.

Comment: First thing to do: run an `explain` on your query - that will tell you if and how it's using indexes ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html)), and also whether you would benefit from allocating more memory. And before anyone says explain doesn't work on updates, it's supported in MyQSL 5.6. You say how many rows you have, but how big is it on disk, and how much is allocated to your InnoDB buffers?

Comment: Does converting to InnoDB give any performance enhancements on large volume tables?  If so, how? Remember this is not an appliaction, I don't need ACID compliance.  Switching to SSD is not an option.  If I was designing a database application I certainly would use Innodb.

Answer (score -1):

MYISAM is very best to Select operation. if your database is very much heavy with good user . Update operation will take time.

try to make join with index column. Join will perform good.

communicate with your mysql server admin tell him/her to increase **join_buffer_size**

join_buffer_size server variable to responsible allocate memory for joins that not perform 
join with index  column

I hope this will help you.

Comment: @NB what is false info. can you tell me truth

Comment: MyISAM can be better with a small number of read-only users, but nothing more than that. It's also very much not crash-proof, so you really don't want to use it in production.